# SQL Server Partially Random Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, pagination, sql-server-2012

I am trying to figure out a way to randomly pull out X records from a table that currently has 129,503 records with more being added fairly regularly, with the caveat being that I need to paginate them, preferably at the database level. Utilizing `newid()` won't work because paging that result set wouldn't be possible as it changes every time, nor is utilizing `TABLESAMPLE` since it doesn't return a guaranteed set of records every time. One thought I had was to possibly generate a random value (i.e. `newid()`) that is stored on every record in here so I could do initial ordering by that (vs. generating it on the fly), but then paging through those results in a consistent manner was a little out of my realm.

Think of this as I need to show every user who visits our site a set of records from this table, but want each user to have a different view (making it look as if it's random), but then would need reliable paging to work with those records per-user so they don't end up with results that have already been seen on a previous page.

This is with SQL Server 2012 so any ideas?

Comment: How big is the table? For a smallish table this is certainly doable. If you can't afford sorting the entire on every query it gets harder.

Comment: 129,503 rows as of the time I wrote it, 129,510 now. So it is having stuff added every hour or so.

Comment: How often will this query be executed? Is it ok to have it run for, say, 100ms? If yes, you can afford to sort all rows for each execution.

Answer (score 0):

Now this is likely to be slow since there will be multiple function calls but you can try:

```
ORDER BY HASHBYTES('SHA1', UserName + PrimaryKey), PrimaryKey
```

There are three parts to this idea.  First the HASHBYTES produces a consistently random output.  Second, including the UserName in the hash means each user will see a different list.  Using the primary key as well means each row will be uniquely and consistently identified.  We also order by just the PrimaryKey in case of an unexpected hash collision.
  There are different hash functions other than SHA1 that you can use.  I am not to familiar with different hash functions, but I believe SHA1 will be quick.  For security and storing passwords this isn't good, but for ordering it should be fine.

Comment: We wouldn't necessarily have a username for this particular part of the site (it's public-facing), but I could just as easily substitute a GUID generated at session startup that would take care of this for me. I have one other idea to play with first and if that doesn't work I'll try this next. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a hardish problem if I understand correctly.  You want a different set of records for each user and you want the ordering to be persistent between multiple SQL calls.  And, the size of the table may change between calls.

A simple approach is to enumerate the records.  Then, just let each user start from a different offset:

```
declare @offset int;

select @offset = rand() * count(*)
from table t;

with data as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as rn,
             count(*) over () as numrecs
      from table t
     )
select t.*
from table t
order by mod(rn + @offset, numrecs);
```

You can then enhance this using a pseudo-random number generator, with a multiplicative factor and offset.  The easiest way would be:

```
declare @offset int;

select @offset = rand(checksum(newid())) * count(*),
       @factor = rand(checksum(newid())) * count(*)
from table t;

with data as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as rn,
             count(*) over () as numrecs
      from table t
     )
select t.*
from table t
order by mod(@factor * rn + @offset, numrecs);
```

It is safer if the `@factor` values are prime numbers.  There are occasional combinations of `@factor` and `numrecs` that could cause small cycles in the results.  But see if this meets your needs.

Comment: We have a consistent average of 20 unique visitors at any given time, so I worry this one would get rough - especially if `@factor` is supposed to be a prime number. When I say unique, I mean in watching Google Analytics, we can see where those accessing the site stays fairly steady at 20, but we'll see it drop to 18, then jump to 22, etc. It's a public-facing site so the number of users could be fairly large.

Comment: This approximates randomness because all users still see the same total order just with different starting points. Not sure if acceptable.

Comment: @usr . . . The first just starts at different offsets.  The second starts at different offsets with different steps.  That should be sufficiently random.